# what is the point of 'timeline' in array or param for get_news_feed?

Tags: getstream-io

I went through all tutorials and docs which `stream-django` provided.

And there was one thing that I could't understand.

I can't find the differences between these feed_manager methods.

```
# (1)
feed = feed_manager.get_news_feed('timeline', request.id)
# (2)
feed = feed_manager.get_news_feed(request.id)['timeline']
# (3)
feed = feed_manager.get_news_feed(request.id)
```

Could you explain the difference? Are they doing exactly same thing? `timeline` means flat feed, then why do we put `timeline` in param?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timeline` is the name of the feed group that you've created within Stream.

Once you create a feed group in Stream, you'll select the type of feed group ("flat" in this case, but can also be "aggregated" or "notification"), then, you'll name the feed group - common names are `timeline`/`news_feed` (a homepage feed showing activity from other users) or `profile`/`user` (a profile page feed showing all activities from a single user). There are no "reserved" words in feed group names.

Re: whether or not these methods are all doing the same thing:

- `feed_manager.get_news_feed('timeline', request.id)` (1) is definitely correct. It'll fetch the feed activities for the specific `timeline:1234` feed, where `1234` is most likely your user's ID.
- (2) and (3) I'm not sure about - it's likely that they're doing the same thing as (1), but I'm not able to tell at the first glance at the docs.

Hopefully that helps!